# Microsoft Teams - Api for meeting start finish or attendees participation start and finish

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to find out duration of meeting joined. There is any api available for get duration of meeting or when meeting start and end

Comment: I need meeting joined time and meeting leave time

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Graph api can read calendar meeting start and end dates. I recommend you start at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer to find what information is available via the simple search features on the link.

Online meeting api options can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/choose-online-meeting-api.